# Visual Studio Code - Indent single line with tabulator-key

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation, text-indent

I would like to know if its possible to indent a single line with the tab-key without deleting the marked text.

In the first part of the GIF you see Visual Studio Code and in the second part Atom. Atom shows the desired behaviour.

[image: First: VS Code, Second: ATOM-Editor]

Thus far it is possible to indent multiple lines this way in VS Code, it also works with backtab, but not with tab and a single line.

[image: VS Code indent multiple lines]

Is this a bug or normal behavior??

My Setup:
Visual Studio Code: Version 1.25.1 (MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra)
Visual Studio Code: Version 1.25.1 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You could use this default keybinding:

{
  "key": "ctrl+]",
  "command": "editor.action.indentLines",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

to tab single or multilines.  If you want that bound to <kbd>tab</kbd> you could modify it to:

```
{
  "key": "tab",
  "command": "editor.action.indentLines",
  "when": "editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

I added the  `editorHasSelection` clause so it operates **only** when something is selected on your line, but then you would lose the normal simple <kbd>tab</kbd> behavior (that you don't like).

Comment: thanks man, your second recommendation does exactly what i want

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, this is the expected behavior. To indent a single line, you'd need to either:

- place cursor at beginning of the line and then tab
- select the entire line (Mac: <kbd>Command+i</kbd>, Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd>) and then tab
- use the indent line command, which can be done with the words selected as shown in your GIF (Mac: <kbd>Command+]</kbd>, Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl+]</kbd>)

There may be [an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) available that gives you your desired behavior, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another flavor here:

In case you want tab to work like shift-tab (where you don't have to highlight anything), AND if you're using tab as the key to accept autocomplete suggestions, use this setting:

```
{
  "key": "tab",
  "command": "editor.action.indentLines",
  "when": "!suggestWidgetVisible && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```